# Object Leds has no attribute animate_stop (ev3dev2 library)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, lego-mindstorms, lego-mindstorms-ev3

First of all I want to sorry for my bad English.

I'm trying to use the ev3dev2 library and Visual Studio Code to add python code to my ev3 robot. My problem is that when I try to use the function 'animate_stop' (or 'animate_flash', 'reset', and some others) from the class 'Leds' I get an error saying that the called function isn't an attribute of the object 'Leds' but when I opened the 'led.py' file (which contains the 'Leds' class) I found all the functions that I tried to call.

I have installed ev3dev2 from github and the official SD card image file for the ev3 from its site.

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env pybricks-micropython

from ev3dev2.led import Leds

Leds().animate_stop
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/robot/ttt/main.py", line 5, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Leds' object has no attribute 'animate_stop'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can list the attributes and methods of a Python object with [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir); I've found this quite helpful while experimenting! `dir(Leds())`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env pybricks-micropython

from ev3dev2.led import Leds

leds = Leds()
leds.all_off()
```